# Workaround for TexShop and multibib

Tags: bibtex, subdividing, texshop, multibib, ide

It looks there is a problem with TexShop and `multibib` package. `multibib` package expects that you do `bibtex xxx` where `xxx` is your own `newcites`. However, when using TexShop it looks like it only does it for the main document. Therefore, the only way I have to make it work is to do it from command line (notice the `bibtex xxx`):

```
 pdflatex main
 bibtex main
 bibtex xxx
 pdflatex main
 pdflatex main
```

Do you know a workaround I can do so that I can latex without problem in any IDE?

Thanks!

Comment: you could write an apple-script which applies `bibtex` to the desired files or simply use `biblatex`

Comment: @bloodworks yes, I could do that. In fact, I already did a .sh that does that for me. Problem is I have several people working in the same project so I wanted to know if there was a way to solve the problem for all of us using whatever IDE/tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `latexmk` engine handles multibib, I think.  If you don't have the `latexmk` Engine installed, go to `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/` and move the `.engine` files from the `Inactive/Latexmk` folder to the `Engines` folder.

Restart TeXShop, and the new engines should appear in the pulldown menu beside the Typeset button in the document window.  If you're using pdflatex as your usual engine, then use pdflatexmk instead.  You can do this automatically by adding the line:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
```

at the beginning of your document. (TeXShop can insert this line for you for any engine you choose by using the Program menu item from the Macros menu.)