# One of my 2 bibliographies will not show up when I typeset

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

So I am editing a paper that I did not write and the paper uses 2 bibliographies, one for references and one for links and I have 2 .bib's named Links and References  This is my minimal code,

```
\usepackage{cite,amssymb}
\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{L}{Links}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\nociteL{*}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{References}{}

\bibliographystyleL{ieeetran}
\bibliographyL{Links}{}

\end{document}
```

in this I get only get the references bibliography and do not ever see the links

Comment: You need to run `bibtex` on each bibliography separately or compile with `latexmk` which can do this automatically.

Comment: There's a full example of how to use `multibib` in this question: [Sectioning bibliography by type of refered item](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246).

Comment: How do I run bibtex on separate files?

Comment: Either do it from the command line (see the example in the link I gave) but more simply use `latexmk`. What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using texshop so I do not have latexmk

Comment: Yes, you most certainly do have it. See [Workaround for TexShop and multibib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61666) on how to access it.

Comment: I retracted my vote. I would like to see a `latexmk`-free answer. (Probably pure TeXShop-engine answer.)

Comment: @Symbol1 If you want an answer without `latexmk` then I would recommend posting a bounty on the linked duplicate. The present question arose simply from a misunderstanding of how `multibib` compilation proceeds, and so reopening it is inappropriate IMO.

Comment: @alanMunn thank you for all your help! Sorry I was a bit slow.  It took me a long time to figure out how to get the engine in the correct folder